# How can I add a data frame as vertex attributes with matching name in R?

Tags: r, networking, igraph

In R, I have graph "gD" as below

```
IGRAPH 40b044a UN-- 17 38 --     
+ attr: name (v/c)    
+ edges from 40b044a (vertex names):    
 [1] Jane     --Jay       Jane     --Brian     Jane     --David     Jane     --Sarah        
 [5] Jane     --Tom       Jay      --Christian Jay      --David     Jay      --Sarah        
 [9] Jay      --Dave      Jay      --Josep     Jay      --Ray       Brian    --David    
[13] Brian    --Sarah     Brian    --Christin  Brian    --Tom       Christian--Sarah    
[17] Christian--Jim       Christian--Dave      Christian--Josep     Michael  --David    
[21] Michael  --Christin  Michael  --Tim       David    --Tim       David    --Tom      
[25] David    --Dave      David    --Zemma     David    --Ray       Jim      --Josep    
[29] Christin --Tom       Christin --Zemma     Tim      --Dickson   Tim      --Zemma    
+ ... omitted several edges
```

And this is org.unit table and I need to add following attribute which is grade and org. 
    org.unit table

```
    name grade             org
1       Jane    11              HR
2        Tom    11         Finance
3      David     9       Marketing
4        Jay     9       Marketing
5      Brian     8             GTO
6  Christian     7             GTO
7        Tim     5 Commercial Bank
```

I tried to use `set.vertex.attribute()`, but I can't figure out how to make it go through a data frame and only add attributes to existing nodes. 
 For example, Jane's grade is 11 in org.unit table.  And I need to first check Jane from graph dD and assign corresponding grade of Jane from org.unit table.

When I tried below, I got error message "Error during wrapup: 3 arguments passed to '$' which requires 2"

```
gD <- gD %>%set_vertex_attr( .,name = 'grade', index = V(gD), value = sapply(V(gD)$name, function(x){org.unit %>% filter( org.unit$name == x) %>% org.unit$grade }))
```

I spent 2 days trying different ways but none of them works. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for trying to include your graph/data, but no one wants to type all of that in.  Instead, please use `dput(gD)` and paste the output into your question so that we can get your graph into R and debug.

Answer (score 0):

You can set attributes of a graph `gD`from a table `tab` like so:

`V(gD)$attribute <- sapply(V(gD)$name, function(x) tab$attribute[tab$virtex.name == x])`

**Small working code example:**

This should mimic your data structure:

```
library(igraph)

# Simple example network similar to your data?
org.unit <- data.frame(name =c("Jane",     "Tom",     "David",       "Jay", "Brian", "Christian",  "Tim"),
                       grade=c(    11,        11,            9,          9,       8,           7,      5),
                       org  =c(  "HR", "Finance", "Marketing", "Marketing",   "GTO",       "GTO", "Bank"))

relations <- data.frame(from=c("Jane",  "Jane",  "Jane",       "Jay",   "Jay", "David"),
                        to = c( "Jay", "Brian", "David", "Christian", "David", "Christian"))

# Make a graph from the relations
gD <- graph.data.frame(relations, directed=TRUE)

# Set virtex atributes
V(gD)$grade <- sapply(V(gD)$name, function(x) org.unit$grade[org.unit$name == x])
V(gD)$org.unit <- sapply(V(gD)$name, function(x) as.character(org.unit$org[org.unit$name == x]))
plot(gD)

# Look at it:
V(gD)$grade
```

**Explanation:**

Using `sapply()` is stupid because it subsets your `org.unit`-table multiple times, but its smart because it guarantees the correct order of the vertices. If your were to merge your table, the order of your attributes would scramble:

```
# Using merge() will scramble your vertex order:
attribute_values <- merge(org.unit, data.frame(name=V(gD)$name), by="name")
(attribute_values$name == V(gD)$name)
```

You could of course sort them to force the order in which they appear in your graph:

```
# If you make an attributes table to set from, it would have to be re-ordered
attribute_values <- attribute_values[ match(attribute_values$name, data.frame(name=V(gD)$name)$name), ]
(attribute_values)
# This is the order of your vertices in the graph
(V(gD)$name)
```

Now you have a nice table in the right order to set vertex-attributes using the method of your preference. You use `set_vertex_attr()`. Any of these would work:

```
V(gD)$grade <- attribute_values$grade
gD <- set_vertex_attr(gD, 'grade', V(gD), attribute_values$grade)
```

**Nota bene:**

All this code supposes that `name` is a unique identifier of your data.frame `org.unit`. If not, "Jane" will have multiple grades and organisations. Confirm that this returns false:

```
# Are there duplicates in org.unit?
!length(unique(org.unit$name)) == length(org.unit$name)
```

If you have multiple nodes named, for example "Jane", the code should handle that but assign to the multiple Janes the same grade and organisation as indicated in `org.unit`.

All the best

Comment: Hi,  It works!!   I don't know how to thank you enough!   : )

Comment: Cool. Glad to help. Please, mark the question as answered if you feel that it is.